# Gradle version issue in dolphin Andriod studio version

Tags: project, android-contentresolver, diamond-problem

After the updating the new version of Android Studio ,I am facing the error message in our Android Studio.

```java
**> Unsupported Gradle. 
> The project uses Gradle version which is incompatible with Android Studio 2021.3.
> 
> Possible solution:
> Open Gradle wrapper settings, upgrade version to 3.0 or newer and reload the project
> **
```

I am try to solve bit it had not solved.

I **created new project** because I think it is temporary error but after all is has not solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend updating Gradle for your project.

You can execute the follwing commands from the command line (in the root directory of your project), or you can just click on the "terminal" tab at the bottom of Android studio.

First, check your Gradle version:

`./gradlew --version`

You will get a lot of results, but you only care about the line that says something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Assuming you are on an earlier version of Gradle, you can update to the latest by using the following command (replacing '7.6' with the version you wish to use):

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.6
```

Depending on your project, that should be all you need. If you have incompatabilities with your code and the version of Gradle, Android studio should issue you further guidance.